# The compiler directive #if does not recognize DEBUG anymore after changing solution to x64

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c-preprocessor

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 C#.

I recently changed all projects in a solution to x64 by using configuration manager in addition to changing the build properties for all projects. Since then, the `#if (DEBUG)` directive doesn't work as if the DEBUG constant vanished.

```
#if (DEBUG)
    // This code does not execute even in debug mode!
#endif
```

I also noticed that instead of the usual `bin\Debug` and `bin\Release` folders, the projects now get compiled into `bin\x64\Debug` and `bin\x64\Release`.

I searched around but most related results covered how to configure `x64` if it does not show by default.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When creating your x64 platform, it's likely your Debug settings for that platform aren't defining the `DEBUG` constant.

In the project's Properties, go to your x64/Debug configuration/platform, and check the "Build" tab.  There is a check box called: "Define DEBUG constant".  Make sure it's checked.

Comment: Thanks. Silly I didn't notice that but friendly behavior for VS should have been to copy settings to the new platform when shifting architectures.